# What are some great papers/publications relating to game programming?

Tags: software-engineering

What are some of your favorite papers and publications that closely relate to game programming? I'm particularly looking for examples that are well-written and illustrated, and/or have had a profound influence on the industry. (Here's one example: [in this GDC talk](http://www.gdcvault.com/play/1014345/I-Shot-You-First-Networking), Bungie's David Aldridge mentions that a paper called "The TRIBES Engine Networking Model" was the starting point for Halo's network code.)

Comment: While an interesting question, it's unfortunately not one suited to this site, see the [faq](http://gamedev.stackexchange.com/faq)

Comment: Community wiki? I don't think it would be a bad thing to put forth a collection of good writings on game programming.

Comment: The problem is that there's no specific question to solve.  This isn't a forum, and just asking for a list of good reading material doesn't help the site fulfill its goals.  "You should only ask practical, answerable questions based on actual problems that you face. Chatty, open-ended questions diminish the usefulness of our site and push other questions off the front page."

Answer (score 5):

Game programming gems 1-8. A compilation of technical papers and various methods used in game programming. Tried to give one answer since it's so open ended